# Why is the bone moving the wrong part of the mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature

Help the mesh is moving at the wrong part when I move the bone!
[image]

Comment: nevermind I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've accidentally weighted the wrong vertices. Select the mesh, enter *Edit Mode*, and select those vertices. Then, click the *Object Data Properties* tab in the properties panel. [image: This icon]

Find `Bone.004` in the *Vertex Groups* area, click it, then click the *Remove* button. Exit *Edit Mode*, and it should be fine.